# Get the installed AutoCAD version in a Windows Service application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, registry, registrykey

I am writing a Windows Service for generating CAD drawings and I need to detect which version is installed in the system.

What is the best way to get the installed AutoCAD version in a Windows Server environment? I know that I can get this info from the registry, but from which key? Is there any specific one for all the AutoCAD versions?

Comment: probably it'd be in `hklm\software\autodesk\autocad\blahblahblah` or similar.

Comment: Failing that perhaps WMI ⇒ Win32_Product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Exactly you can found it here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD
```

Then you can find value string name: CurVer
It will say installed version.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use Registry Key:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Autodesk\\AutoCAD");
var stringArray = key.GetSubKeyNames();
```

Now, stringArray is an array of strings containing all versions of installed AutoCADs.

Note1: It returns something like "R19.1" which you can easily link to the AutoCAD version, for example, "R19.1" is for AutoCAD 2021.

Note2: Don't forget to install Microsoft.Win32.Registry NuGet Package and include Microsoft.Win32.Registry.

Answer (score 0):

Can also probably check the installed folders under C:Program Files/Autodesk/ and get folder names that contain "AutoCAD". Then split the strings to get the year version.

Something like this. Not checked though:

```
private List<string> GetAutoCadVersions()
{
    List<string> autoCadVersions = new List<string>();
    string cadDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Autodesk";

    if (Directory.Exists(cadDirectory))
    {
        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(cadDirectory);

        foreach (string directory in directories)
        {
            if (directory.Contains("AutoCAD "))
            {
                string version = directory.Remove(0, 7); // Check this is correct end position, output should be eg. 2022, 2023

                autoCadVersions.Add(version);
            }
        }

        if (autoCadVersions.Count > 0)
        {
            // Do check here if there are no directories.
        }
    }

    return autoCadVersions;
}
```

Comment: provide more details like sample code

Comment: Added sample in original comment.